# Multiple Music libraries

Tags: music, music-player

My primary music library is English music (~15 GB) but I have a huge (>10 GB) of Hindi music too. My problem is:

1. I want to maintain these two libraries (preferably on the same device)
2. I want the songs on the Hindi music library to not show up when I "Shuffle All".

How I managed this until now was that I have been using iPod and I check the "Skip while Shuffling" for the Hindi songs. On Android, I can't figure out a way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide media in any folder showing up, you need to add `.nomedia` file to it. If you search your device, using file explorer (either stock or your preferred),you are likely to find quite a few of these scattered around. Copy-paste one of these into the folder you want to hide (Hindi in your case) and the contents should not show up in your player

If you can't find `.nomedia` file, you can easily [create](http://www.techabrel.com/2015/01/how-to-create-nomedia-file-in-android.html)

If you want an  app to do this and offer more functionalities, you could try [nomedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.droida.nomedia) app from play store. It offers you the flexibility of choosing folders to hide. App claims to do this (Works on 4.4.2 on Honor 6)

"A tiny tool to hide multimedia files and prevent media scanning. Touch and hold the directory to toggle. Media library will not display the files in red colored folders."

Alternatively, you could use [MortPlayer Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer), taken from [Izzy's](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay)  list, which takes the approach of choosing which folders you want to play and which folders you want to ignore. It over rides `.nomedia` file presence and provides an easier alternative

Thanks to [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130132/multiple-music-libraries/130137#comment162295_130137) for completing the solution and suggesting alternatives

Comment: And which folders should be hidden? If OP hides the Hindi music, it cannot be played at all – and only the English library is left. So that's no (full) solution; you're missing an essential part: How to play Hindi then? Hint: There are players not using the media library but going by folders, see my list [FolderPlay & AudioBooks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay). A combination could work here.