# How to restrict some tracks from playing in 'Shuffle tracks'

Tags: music

I have some audio tracks on my phone that I want to be excluded from general music playing.  For example, I have some meditations, which I love, but only want to play them when I explicitly choose them, not during shuffle at a party :p

I've just transitioned from iPhone. In Itunes, there is the option on each song to include in playback or not.

Is there anything like this the music app on Android?

Comment: That's not a standard feature of Android. However, you can place these meditation tracks in a separate folder and use a third party *folder play* apps from Izzy's [list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay)

Comment: Related [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/130132/131553) where Mort Music Player worked for OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all of my non-music files in to their own folders.  I use 'My Files'  to copy a '.nomedia' file from some folder (ie: from anki or whatsapp), and paste it in to the non-music folder.

This stops the media files from showing up in 'Music'.

I then use Mort Music - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer  to listen to the audio-books and meditation folders.